# Limit at infinity heine definition, true or false

Tags: calculus, limits

True/False:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous.
>
> For every non-negative sequence of reals $x_n$, which satisfies:
>
> $lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$
>
> The sequence $f(x_n)$, has a convergent sub-sequence, which converges to a real.
>
> Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L\in\mathbb{R}$

My bet is that this is true, and here's my statement:

Let the above conditions hold. Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be non-negative sequences of reals, which tend to infinity as $n\to\infty$.

Assume $f(x)$ doesn't have a limit at infinity.

Let $n_k$ be a strictly increasing sequence of naturals, and let $x_{n_k}$ be a sub-sequence of $x_n$, and $y_{n_k}$ a sub-sequence of $y_n$.

We know that $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k}) = A\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(y_{n_k}) = B\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now we know $f$ has no limit, so we can assume $A\neq B$.

Define $(z_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} = x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...$

We know $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$.

But $f(z_{n_k})$ diverges, contradiction.

Does this hold? Is this even right?

Comment: Going to infinity is not the only way a function can fail to have a limit.

Answer (score 3):

How about $f(x)=\sin(x)$?

Each sequence $f(x_n)$ as described in the problem is bounded, and hence has a convergent subsequence.